# magento 2.2. Community configuration DHL This shipping method is currently unavailable

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-methods, magento-community, dhl

[image]

I have already setting like this one. 
and when I go to **checkout** on option **shipping method** there show

> This **shipping method** is **currently unavailable**. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

on `DHL` option.

[image]

is that beacuse I did wrong configuration or what? because `gateway url` from `DHL indonesia`.

thanks in advance

Comment: yeah it is because of the gateway url. you better contact dhl for that

Comment: thanks you. yup after I change it to be https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet 

and must check this one too.

Stores > Config > shipping settings > origin